Problem with the bootstrap-datepicker showing twice on page load
Thanks in advance for your help!
I have added a version of the bootstrap-datepicker onto my website page.
However for some reason it is displaying twice when it is only supposed to be showing once. Not every time though, sometimes I load the page and it shows once. Other times I load the page and it shows twice.
None of the dependent files are included twice so I am baffled.
Here is the datepicker I have used: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
<div class="span5 col-md-8" id="sandbox-container"><div></div></div>

<script>          
$('#sandbox-container').datepicker({
    startDate: "05/01/2024",
    maxViewMode: 2,
    multidate: false,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,1,2,3,4,5",
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "6",
    todayHighlight: true,
    datesDisabled: ['05/06/2024', '05/21/2024'],
    toggleActive: true
});    
</script>

Can anyone help?
Thanks!
